# JFrame LifeCycle

Tags: java, swing, jframe, lifecycle

Similar to start method in applet which gets called when applet window is minimized and maximized, is there some similar method which gets called when we switch control back and forth between JFrame and some other windows (such as notepad) ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your looking for [WindowListener#windowActivated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowActivated%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29) and [WindowListener#windowdeactivated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowDeactivated%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29)

You need to attach a listener to the frame via JFrame#addWindowListener

Answer (score 3):

In Java Swing every kind of `Window`, including `JFrame` which itself extends the `Window` class, can listen to focus events and so can be notified when gaining or losing focus. Just call the `addWindowFocusListener` on your `JFrame` object, passing a `WindowFocusListener` object that will receive and deal with `FocusEvent`s.
You can refer to the [JFrame documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowFocusListener%28java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener%29) for more detailed explanation.